# Reading from multiple files and storing data in a list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to read print search for all files in a directory and store contents in each file in a list to be used.

My problem is when i use print to debug if the file exists, it prints out the current file or first file in the list. However, It complains that file is not found when i try to read from this file

```
import re
import os
# Program to extract emails from text files


def path_file():
    #path = raw_input("Please enter path to file:\n> ")
    path = '/home/holy/thinker/leads/'
    return os.listdir('/home/holy/thinker/leads') # returns a list like ["file1.txt", 'image.gif'] # need to remove trailing slashes

# read a file as 1 big string
def in_file():

    print path_file()
    content = []
    for a_file in path_file(): # ['add.txt', 'email.txt']
        print a_file
        fin = open(a_file, 'r') 
        content.append(fin.read()) # store content of each file
        print content
        fin.close()
    return content


print in_file()

# this is the error i get
""" ['add.txt', 'email.txt']
add.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Extractor.py", line 24, in <module>
    print in_file()
  File "Extractor.py", line 17, in in_file
    fin = open(a_file, 'r') 
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'add.txt'
"""
```

The error I get is aboive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.listdir` will return you only file name. You have to directory name on before that file name.

Its trying to open `add.txt` in same directory where you ran your program. Please add directory name before file name.

```
def path_file():
    #path = raw_input("Please enter path to file:\n> ")
    path = '/home/holy/thinker/leads/'
    return [os.path.join(path, x) for x in os.listdir(path)]
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use the full path of the file you want to read.

so please do `fin = open(os.path.join(r'/home/holy/thinker/leads/', a_file), 'r')`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a rewrite using `glob` to limit which files are considered;

```
import glob
import os
import re
import sys

if sys.hexversion < 0x3000000:
    # Python 2.x
    inp = raw_input
else:
    # Python 3.xrange
    inp = input

def get_dir(prompt):
    while True:
        dir_name = inp(prompt)
        dir_name = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), dir_name)
        if os.path.isdir(dir_name):
            return dir_name
        else:
            print("{} does not exist or is not a directory".format(dir_name))

def files_in_dir(dir_name, file_spec="*.txt"):
    return glob.glob(os.path.join(dir_name, file_spec))

def file_iter(files):
    for fname in files:
        with open(fname) as inf:
            yield fname, inf.read()

def main():
    email_dir   = get_dir("Please enter email directory: ")
    email_files = files_in_dir(email_dir, "*.eml")

    print(email_files)

    content = [txt for fname,txt in file_iter(email_files)]
    print(content)

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

and a trial run looks like

```
Please enter email directory: c:\temp
['c:\\temp\\file1.eml', 'c:\\temp\\file2.eml']
['file1 line one\nfile1 line two\nfile1 line three',
 'file2 line one\nfile2 line two']
```